# Using embedded jetty, how I link a ServerConnector to a Server?

Tags: embedded-jetty, connector

More specifically, what's the difference between `ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server)` and `server.addConnector(connector)`? Are they exclusive? Redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One creates, one uses.

```java
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
```

That creates a `ServerConnector`, initialized from the state of the Server (various configuration, threadpools, schedulers, bufferpools, beans, etc) at that point in time.

```java
server.addConnector(connector);
```

That uses the connector, by adding it to the server for bean and lifecycle management.